# Client session id not found in Kubernetes

Tags: java, groovy, kubernetes, sessionid

The source of the client session id is WebUtils.getSessionId(request) using java(groovy actually).  The value is shown in the regular war deployment, but not in Kubernetes.

How to retrieve client session id in Kubernetes?

Comment: Can you share how your requests are coming into K8s?  Through a service? Through an Ingress?  If yes, can you share the details for those?

Comment: @Rico, yes, it should from Ingress. What kind of details do you need? Sorry I'm new to ingress as well

Comment: Look for examples using ingress and session stickiness using cookie.